# Import-StartLayout Pinned Taskbar Apps Moving

Tags: xml, powershell, automation

I'm new to PowerShell and I had a question.
I'm using Import-StartLayout to automatically pin certain apps to the taskbar for every new user that gets created on my machine. It works, but I noticed that when I pin something new to the taskbar and log off and back in, the newly attached pinned app get pushed all the way to the left, and the apps set in the .xml file get pushed to the right. Is there a way to make the pinned apps stop moving?

Contents of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LayoutModificationTemplate
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification"
    xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout"
    xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout"
    xmlns:taskbar="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/TaskbarLayout"
    Version="1">
  <CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection PinListPlacement="Replace">
    <defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
      <taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\File Explorer.lnk" />
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" /> 
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" /> 
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" />
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" />
      </taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
    </defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
  </CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```